# iOS Line Graph Using X,Y Axis

Tags: ios, objective-c

I searched many forums. But i need to Draw Line  with X,Y Start point to Another X,Y End point. But i am not getting any solutions.

This is Asp.net code. I need something look like similer.

```
Grap.AddPoint(0, 0, "ff0000", "Red Line")
Graph.AddPoint(30, 30, "ff0000", "")
Graph.AddPoint(0, 0, "00ff00", "Green Line")
Graph.AddPoint(30, 20, "00ff00", "")
```

My Points.

Line 1:

From (0,0)
To (75,18)

Line 1:

From (0,0)
To (75,9)

[image: This is Result i am expecting in Objective C]

Check Below Image for your reference.

[image]

Comment: There are many graphs library on github. If you want to draw your own, you can learn CoreGraphics, subclass UIView and override the UIView's drawRect. If you want your graph to be interactive, then subclass UIControl instead.

Comment: yes. but there is no one relevant to what i expected. can you send link?

Comment: https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph

Comment: Sorry.I already checked this. This is not relevant to my concept.

Comment: Then no choice u make by your own by coregraphics.